# JasperReport - condition in TextElement

Tags: jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I'm new at JasperReports. 
I want to get italic text when some variable will be set at '3'.

Here's my code:

```
<textElement>

    <font size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1250" isPdfEmbedded="true"
    isItalic=<![CDATA[$F{variable}==3 ? "true" : "false"]]> />

</textElement>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried also make conditional style but wherever I put  i recive error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use set value of the property `isItalic` (and many others) with help of expressions.

In your case you should use the *`conditional style`*.

The sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <style name="customStyle">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{variable} == 3]]></conditionExpression>
            <style isItalic="true"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    ...
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="customStyle" mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```